# For each row do update

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a big query to create a suport table like a temp table but not temp,
One of the fields on my query to create this table is very problematic, without him i create a 50k rows table with lots of subquerys in 15 seconds.
With this field i just can't run, my 4gb ram just gone all and don't finish the query,
so I've take out this field, and i run the query without the field, create the table and after that i'll runs other query just to update one by one.

My field query is this one:

```
(select GROUP_CONCAT(nome) from con_classificador where FIND_IN_SET(id,(SELECT CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(fk),GROUP_CONCAT(pac.fk_classificador))
                                    FROM prod_assoc_classificador AS pac
                                    LEFT JOIN con_classificador AS cc4 ON pac.fk_classificador = cc4.id
                                    where pac.fk_produto = #HERE ID#)) and id != 7) AS categorias_texto
```

So i have this table aux with fk_produto, and i'need to join it with this subquery and get the result and update each row.

So i have this categorias_texto row on my aux table, and need to feed it with this query and #HERE ID # its a must have to join both aux table and this subquery

I know its kinda crazy but i don't know how i can explain better.

Answer (score 2):

Try it with a `JOIN` which is efficient than `SUBQUERY`

```
update 
tableA as ta 
inner join tableB as tb on ta.fk_product = tb.id
set ta.title = tb.title
```